# VBA create dictionary aggregate values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have six variables, symbolizing three pairs (key/value). It will always be three pairs.

```
cb1 = 1: cb1value = 10
cb2 = 1: cb2value = 20
cb3 = 8: cb3value = 10
```

What I'm failing at is aggregating the values in a dictionary according to the key.
So in the above case the result would be:

```
1, (10, 20)
8, (10)
```

The end goal here is to use Sum(key) to get the total per key.

EDIT: Thanks for the replies so far. Maybe I'm just thinking too complicated. First I've put all the values in an array and then loop through it.

```
MyArray = Array(cb1, cb1value, cb2, cb2value, cb3, cb3value)
```

Now the keys are every 2 steps, so in my loop:

```
For i = 0 To 5 Step 2
    If Not (keywords.Exists(MyArray(i))) Then
        keywords.Add MyArray(i), Collection(MyArray(i + 1))
    Else
        'If the key exists, the value should be added to the existing key's collection. **But how?**
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Why not add when building the dictionary? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Share your code that you use to build this. Perhaps we can help you add values to your existing keys. This seems like a strange usecase for a dictionary, but it could work.

Comment: The values could be collections to which new values are added as they are encountered

Comment: I have edited my post. Adding the values to the collections as they are encountered would be a nice solution, however, I'm not sure if that's possible?

Comment: `keywords(myArray(i)) = keywords(myArray(i)) + Collection(MyArray(i + 1))` should do the job in that `Else` block.

Comment: @JNevill This is producing an error (Invalid procedure call or argument). Tim Williams has posted an answer that is working though. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
For i = lbound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)-1 Step 2 
    If Not (keywords.Exists(MyArray(i))) Then keywords.Add MyArray(i), New Collection
    keywords(MyArray(i)).Add MyArray(i + 1)
Next i
```

To get the sum of all entries in a collection:

```
Function SumCollection(col as Collection)
    Dim rv As Double, i
    For Each i in col
        rv = rv + i
    Next i
    SumCollection = rv
End Function
```

If all you need is the sum though, you don't need the collection: just sum directly in the dictionary as you add each item.

Comment: Thanks exactly what I wanted. How can I sum though because this doesn't seem to work: Debug.Print Application.Sum(keywords.item(1))

Comment: @TinMan - did you test that? OP is asking how to sum a single value from the dictionary.  You cannot pass a Collection to Sum

Comment: @TinMan Hi TinMan, sorry my post seems all over the place. What I meant was using a dictionary with a possibility of multiple values per key. I assumed using either an Array or Collection would be perfect for my use case and Tim Williams provided the solution for my problem. The Array I'm using comes into play because I'm saving the initial values inside it and looping through it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply tutu. @TimWilliams as usual you are correct. I reread the post and answer they both make sense.